# Symfony2 http cache invalidate on logout

Tags: php, symfony, session, caching

I am having problem that I can not figure out how to solve after investing lots of hours.

I am using simple http cache in my application and I set that on karnel so that all pages have cache.

this is my caching code:

```
# myapp/src/MyWebBundle/EventListener/MyCacheListener.php 


namespace MyWebBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;


class MyCacheListener
{
private $authorizationChecker;
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
}

public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();

    if($this->tokenStorage->getToken() != null && $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")) {
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('public', true);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 86400);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
        //$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
    } else if ($this->tokenStorage->getToken() != null && $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")) {
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
    }
    return $response;
}


}
```

Then In my service.yml

```
my_web.event_listener.my_cache_listener:
      class: MyWebBundle\EventListener\MyCacheListener
      arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker", "@security.token_storage"]
      tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

my logout success handler

```
/**
 * logout success handler. removes the client login by client id
 *
 * @param Request        $request
 * @param Response       $response
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 */
public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
{
    $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
    $attributes = $token->getAttributes();
    $clientId = $attributes['device_id'];
    $dql = sprintf("delete My\UserBundle\Entity\ClientLogin login
        where login.device_id = '%s'", $clientId);
    $result = $this->em
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->execute();
    $request->getSession()->invalidate();       


    @todo: for now redirecting to '/'. In future need get the target
    //from security.yml
    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, '/');
}
```

now what am i am doing user is logged in there is no cache and if not then all contents will be cached.The problem is if I logged in and then click logged out the session is destroyed as per the handler but I still see the logout button and if I click on that button again I am getting error because the session is null but again trying to logout. but if I refresh the page manually then I can see the login button there not logout.

How can I solve the logged out problem while have everything cached? I don't want to use gateway cache or FOSHttp cache now

Comment: Are you sure it is cached? Does the server return a 304 or a 200? If you disable caching in your browser alltogether, does that fix the problem?

Also, onKernelResponse doesn't seem to return a $response object but it seems that you need to modify the $event parameter. So Instead of putting the response object into $response, try to modify it directly via $event->getResponse()->headers... and return nothing.